# Check battery status Arch Linux installation ISO

Tags: arch-linux, console

I'm up to reinstall Arch on my laptop while I have a bit of a time and I've encountered an interesting question to ask.

Is there any way to check my laptop battery status without installing acpi package? (as I'm currently offline without charger and I can't get neither of them)

I thought that system should keep track of a battery level somehow. So is it possible to display that info in CLI?

Comment: Have a look at the files in `/sys/class/power_supply/`. May or may not work for your particular hardware.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The kernel provides this information through `/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/capacity`

Simply `cat` this path to get the information (in percent of your batteries capacity):

```
cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/capacity
```

For an live view you can combine `cat` with the command `watch`. The following command provides you an, updated, live status of your batteries capacity:

```
watch -n0 cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/capacity
```

If your system has more then one battery, `BAT0` under `/sys/class/power_supply/` maybe `BAT1`, `BAT2` or something different. Look at the devices under `ls /sys/class/power_supply/` and cat their information.

Comment: I use Alpine Linux and in power_supply I have AC (Alternate Current) and CMB1 using my Laptop.CMB1/capacity shows 95. Thanks for the watch command, `0` is the seconds.